# Regex (flavor: PCRE) filter for matching first instance of character string THEN only filter in context of that first instance?

Tags: regex

I want to match the first instance of "start" within this initial string

```
abcdstartabcdstartghijstartghij
```

I used the following regex to (not greedy) grab everything through the first "start."

```
^.*?start
```

Now, I filter for the FIRST instance of "start" with "ghij" attached to it.

When I tried the following, it filtered up to the SECOND "start" with "ghij"

```
^.*?startghij
```

My problem is I want it so that it CANNOT find "start" with "ghij" because "ghij" is NOT with the first "start". Basically I want that latter filter to fail.

What regex filter would filter for that first instance and only in context of that first instance? It should not go to the second "start" even though that has "ghij".

I hope my example explained my question a little more clearly.

Comment: What variety of regex are you using? PCRE, JavaScript, ???

Comment: @Nick my apologies I'm simply learning Regex flavor PCRE on regex101. I'll update the question.

Comment: Do you want to match all instances of `start` not followed by `ghij` and all instances of `startghij` not preceded by `start`?

Comment: @caryswoveland I only want the first instance not followed by ghij. My goal is to get an error if I land the first instance of start and there is no ghij.  I'm learning there probably  isn't a way to do an action for a specific nth occurence.

Comment: I don't understand your comment. In your example the first instance of `start` is followed by `abcd`. You say you want the first instance not followed by `ghij`, so the first instance of `smart` qualifies. But then you say you want to raise an error if the first instance of `smart` (i.e., the same one followed by `abcd`) is not followed by `ghij`.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as "on the n-th occurrence of ... also do ...", at least not directly. View the problem of the n-th occurence as "there were `n - 1` occurrences before". 
In your case you look for the first occurrence which means exactly no occurrences before.
So instead of the `.*?` part you need to [match a string not containing a certain substring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406230/regular-expression-to-match-a-line-that-doesnt-contain-a-word).

In your case this would become something like this:

```
^(?:(?!start).)*?startghij
```

This should work on most regex flavors as well.